# Is it possible that echo command break the so file?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I want to add version string to my so file, then I use:

```
echo "v1.01" >> aa.so
```

and the version is add to the tail of aa.so

However, I wonder that if this method has any possibility that break the so file? Or we can add infinite bytes to the end of a so file and will not break its structure?

PS: Except for file signature, because aa.so is build by myself.

Comment: There are proper ways to add version information to a shared object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `echo "v1.01" >> aa.so`, the string `v1.01` will be appended after the symbol table and will look like as it's an entry:

```
$ hexedit file.so
...
00000F40   6F 6E 5F 73  74 61 72 74  5F 5F 00 5F  4A 76 5F 52  on_start__._Jv_R
00000F50   65 67 69 73  74 65 72 43  6C 61 73 73  65 73 00 5F  egisterClasses._
00000F60   66 69 6E 69  00 5F 5F 62  73 73 5F 73  74 61 72 74  fini.__bss_start
00000F70   00 5F 65 6E  64 00 70 75  74 73 40 40  47 4C 49 42  ._end.puts@@GLIB
00000F80   43 5F 32 2E  30 00 66 75  6E 63 74 69  6F 6E 00 5F  C_2.0.function._
00000F90   65 64 61 74  61 00 5F 5F  63 78 61 5F  66 69 6E 61  edata.__cxa_fina
00000FA0   6C 69 7A 65  40 40 47 4C  49 42 43 5F  32 2E 31 2E  lize@@GLIBC_2.1.
00000FB0   33 00 5F 69  6E 69 74 00  76 31 2E 30  31 0A        3._init.v1.01.
---  file.so       --0xFB0/0xFBE-----------------------------------------------
$
```

However, there will be no index or reference to that string:

```
$ readelf -s file.so
...
    43: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
    44: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _Jv_RegisterClasses
    45: 00000498     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _fini
    46: 000015c0     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS __bss_start
    47: 000015c8     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _end
    48: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND puts@@GLIBC_2.0
    49: 0000044c    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 function
    50: 000015c0     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _edata
    51: 00000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.1
    52: 00000328     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 _init
$
```

so it shouldn't be a problem in this case and it will not break the file. but, it doesn't feel right to do so.

Usually shared libraries include the version in there names:

```
$ ls /lib | grep .so
ld-2.11.3.so
ld-linux.so.2
libacl.so.1
libacl.so.1.1.0
libanl-2.11.3.so
libanl.so.1
libatasmart.so.4
libatasmart.so.4.0.3
libattr.so.1
libattr.so.1.1.0
...
$
```

You can do the same and add the version to your shared library, for example `aa.so.1.01`. If you are the author of this library you can also export some function to get the version of the library:

```
const char *version(void) {
  return "1.01";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that(echo "v1.01" >> aa.so) on My Ubuntu PC, with an SO that contains three API, and called the three API one by one, then it gaved the supposed result. So I think it is all right.

And yes, its file signature is changed, but that does not affect my API invocation.

Comment: @aragaer Yes, that is a question. But it can be solve by `fseek` to the end of file and go back for a size that the version information specified, then read the version information.

Comment: @scvyao Excellent bash solution.

Comment: @scvyao Yes, as you've presented. I've given a c answer which is not necessarily cumbersome.